# Is the general member of a linear system containing an irreducible and nonsingular curve also irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a non-singular projective rational surface over an algebraically closed field and $C \subset X$ is a non-singular irreducible rational curve on $X$ such that the complete linear system $|C|$ is positive dimensional.

Does it follow that the general member $|C|$ is nonsingular and irreducible, or at least irreducible?

My initial idea to deal with this was using Bertini Theorem, which claims that if $|C|$ does not have fixed components and the dimension of the rational map
$$
\Phi: X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, \mathcal{L}(C)))
$$
induced by $|C|$ is greater or equal than $2$, then the general member is irreducible. So instead one could ask

Does $C$ irreducible and non-singular imply $\dim \Phi(X) \ge 2$?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes with fewer assumptions (you don't need rationality of the kind you mention ). The second one is false in general. Take  $X=C\times \mathbb{P}^1$ for a smooth projective curve $C$ and the linear system $|C\times p|$  for some point $p$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give any pointer or a reference that would help on how to see the first claim? Does Bertini imply that the locus of the irreducible divisors is always contains an open of $|C|$?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand my comment. Blow up the finitely many (possibly) points in the base locus of $|C|$, to get a morphism $f:X\to Y$ with a fiber precisely $C$. Then, either use Bertini (or Stein factorization) to show that general fiber is irreducible. Then show that these are general elements of $|C|$.